# Providing Poor man's dashboard app communication

Tags: javascript, extjs, rally

I realize you are coming up with a way for panels to communicate.  Until that time, I was thinking I could get some basic communication going with a preference object.

But how do I find a unique ID for the dashboard where an app resides?

In case there might be a better solution than sharing info via a preference object, let me describe the specific problem we want to solve:  Certain projects within our project structure represent "programs" for which we want to display a "metrics dashboard"-- that dashboard would consist of multiple apps on a shared dashboard.  But programs are not at consistent levels in the rally project hierarchy, and we only have about four programs though we have many many rally projects.

Because of this, I'd like this code metrics dashboard to be one page in Rally, which can easily switch between the various programs we have.  I would prefer not to use the project hierarchy to do this, because we have a lot of projects, and its time consuming and tricky to find and select the programs.

Comment: Did you intend to send this to the Rally developers?

Comment: We lurk in here so it is a good way to get ask us question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hacked at the sample to create an example of an app that can pass events between two panels.
This is very unsupported at this time and we reserve the right to break it whenever we want without any warning.

That being said you can see the current unsupported way to get an Apps ID and if you make two copies of this App you can see in your console the results of the Apps communicating on the global Rally message bus.

You can find the gist of it [here](https://gist.github.com/2845161)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Custom App</title>

    <!--Include SDK-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/2.0p/sdk.js"></script>

    <!--App code-->
    <script type="text/javascript">

        Rally.onReady(function() {

            Ext.define('CustomApp', {
                extend: 'Rally.app.App',
                componentCls: 'app',
                mixins:['Rally.Messageable'],
                launch: function() {
                    var brokenInTheFutureIdThatWillWorkForNow =   Ext.Object.fromQueryString(window.location.href);
                    window.parent.Rally.Messages.subscribe("test",function(){console.error(brokenInTheFutureIdThatWillWorkForNow.panelOid,arguments);});
                    window.parent.Rally.Messages.publish("test",brokenInTheFutureIdThatWillWorkForNow.panelOid);
                    //Write app code here
                }
            });

            Rally.launchApp('CustomApp', {
                name: 'My Custom App'
            });

        });

    </script>

    <!--App styles-->
    <style type="text/css">

        .app {
            /* Add app styles here */
        }

    </style>

</head>
<body class="myApp">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is super awesome-- I was able to put together some nice communicating apps with this where I'm doing some queries one app, creating a data store, and then sharing that same data store with several apps.  To me, I think the message bus is really key technology for the Rally strategy of focusing on apps to continue to expand the platform

Comment: I have found some problems with the message bus-- If I refresh the entire page, the apps work fine, but if I move to this page from another rally page via a rally menu, I get an exception when publishing a new message.  I was able to get around this by catching the exception and refreshing the entire page (parent.location.reload(true)), but obviously this is not ideal. Can't wait for your supported solution on this.

Comment: Yeah we are working on it making it into something powerful and easy to use. Right now there are going to be some problems with it and there is not a ton you can do about it. That exception is probably that the event is not unregistered when the App is destroyed. You could do some magic around making it work.

Are you able to share the Apps you are working on? I am very interested in what you are making.
Tweet it out with a #RallyApps tag or better yet put it up on GitHub so others can riff off of it.

Comment: This app in particular requires a bit of infrastructure behind it to make any sense, so I don't think it would be practical to post-- we are saving KLOC, Static Analysis, Coverage and other stats for various programs to Rally in preference objects.  Without those, the app has nothing to report.  I've got a central grid that queries displays summary metrics, and the other panels display various trend graphs.

Comment: If you have a screenshot that doesn't show any sensitive data that would rock too. :)